# RegEx on JS not replaceing

Tags: javascript, regex

i have the next code:

```
 textResponse = textResponse.replace(/<head>(.|\n)*?<\/head\>/img, '');
 alert("Ups, Error " + jqxhr.status + ", " + textResponse);
```

it is used to display an error on an ajax req, the text response contains the html of the response page error, im striping that page of unnecessary content, so i try to remove the `<head>` from the flowing string text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No hay usuario logeado</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Error de servidor en la aplicación '/HMSW'.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
```

...

but the string continues exactly the same, nothing is removed.

any idea why?

Comment: Well, one possibility is best expressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1243641

Comment: I've checked  document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/<head>(.|\n)*?<\/head\>/img, ''); and as far as I can see it works as expected. Probably the issue is not is regex, but in textResponse?

Answer (score 1):

- To include newline characters use `[\s\S]` ("whitespace + nonwhitespace") and don't use multiline processing as it doesn't process the input text as a whole but line by line. The global flag is superfluous since there could be only one `<head>`.

  ```
  textResponse = textResponse.replace(/<head>[\s\S]*?<\/head>/i, '');
  ```
- A better method would be to parse the response into a DOM tree and remove the `head` node.

  The advantage is that the parser will handle correctly a possibly commented duplicate `<head>` or `</head>` (e.g. `<html><head>......<!-- </head> --!>.....</head>`).

  An example using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) which works on modern browsers:

  ```
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textResponse, "text/html");
  doc.head.remove(); // Note: .head node is always present even if empty
  ```

  Then the contents can be imported with [document.importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode):

  ```
  var container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.appendChild(document.importNode(doc.querySelector(".something"), true));
  ```

  or can be extracted as html: `doc.documentElement.outerHTML`

  P.S. The parsing stage may be skipped if [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)'s `responseType` is set to `document`:

  ```
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = "document";
  xhr.open("GET", "http://someurl");
  xhr.onload = function() {
      var doc = this.responseXML;
      doc.head.remove();
      ..................
  };
  xhr.send();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that regular expressions are not suitable to parse HTML, this case can be much easier to process if you simply find the `<body>` tag and closing tag and pick everything in between. Simply do 2 `indexOf()` and grab the content between:

```js
var fullHTMLStr = '<html><head>blablabla</head><body bgColor="white">Body!</body></html>';
var start = fullHTMLStr.indexOf('<body'); // don't look for '>', there might be attributes
var start = fullHTMLStr.indexOf('>', start + 4) + 1; // advance past '>'
var end = fullHTMLStr.indexOf('</body', start);

var justBody = fullHTMLStr.substring(start, end);

alert(justBody);
```